# Special text to latin characters in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas data frame:

```
the_df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2],'name':['Joe','']})
the_df
    id  name
0   1   Joe
1   2
```

As you can see, we can read the second name as "Sarah", but it's written with special characters.

I want to create a new column with these characters converted to latin characters. I have tried this approach:

```
the_df['latin_name'] = the_df['name'].str.extract(r'(^[a-zA-Z\s]*)')
the_df
    id  name    latin_name
0   1   Joe     Joe
1   2
```

But it doesn't recognize the letters. Please, any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "As you can see, we can read the second name as "Sarah", but it's written with special characters." Okay, and do you have any particular rule in mind for deciding that `` should turn into `S`, and not into any other letter? (Why not do it the other way around, for example?) Or do you want to use someone else's pre-determined mapping?

Comment: It could be as complicated as trying to read letters with machine learning, but I wondered if anyone on SO knows if those letters are sort of encoded or are subject to a specific encoding. It seems that with the answer below it is possible to normalize the letters. Anyway, I appreciate the questions you posed, it made me question what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: @Alexis well, `str` objects in Python are just sequences of unicode code points, i.e. they are "unicode strings". The unicode standard defines a few different ways of "normalizing" unicode strings, depending on what you want exactly. Read a bit about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize)

Comment: Whoa, that's what I like from SO, it makes me investigate more. Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga on the unicode strings subject!

Comment: `print(list(hex(ord(c)) for c in ''))` prints
`['0x1d4ae', '0x1d4b6', '0x1d4c7', '0x1d4b6', '0x1d4bd']`. These chars are from the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols block. https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/mathematical-alphanumeric-symbols/

Comment: Hello @TerryJanReedy, thank you!, didn't know about function `hex`, and the link you provided helps! Have a great day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`.str.normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.1/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.normalize.html#pandas-series-str-normalize)

```
the_df['name'].str.normalize('NFKC').str.extract(r'(^[a-zA-Z\s]*)')
```

Output:

```
       0
0    Joe
1  Sarah
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I assume [this is what is being used underneath the hood](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize), but it's convenient that it is a part of the `.str` special methods

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yep, I just did some research on this about three weeks ago, it was fresh in my mind.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and answer @Scott Boston. I was reading about the meaning of 'NFKC' and the documentation on normalize. Have a great day.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize):

```py
>>> import unicodedata
>>> df['name'].apply(lambda x: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x))
0      Joe
1    Sarah
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and time @ThePyGuy, it's great to learn more about the unicodedata library!