# Deleting the extra b after converting accented characters to ASCII

Tags: python

I have the following string:

```
my_string = 'Climate change effects on El Niño by Alberto Mesón'
```

And I want to convert the accented and Spanish characters to ASCII (So the expected string is "Climate change effects on El Nino by Alberto Meson". So I tried this after a solution on SO: [Special text to latin characters in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68671051/special-text-to-latin-characters-in-python)

But it didn't work as expected:

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',my_string)
'Climate change effects on El Niño by Alberto Mesón'
```

Then I tried this and the result was:

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFD', my_string).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
b'Climate change effects on El Nino by Alberto Meson'
```

It is the text I want, but how can I get rid of the `b'`?

Comment: pass it to `.decode('utf8')`

Comment: There *is no 'b'* in the string (well, other than the one in Alberto).  That's just the normal `repr()` of a bytestring, anything that actually uses the characters of the string will not see that 'b'.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#converting-to-bytes

Comment: @ilias-sp, your solution worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bytestring. You can call decode() on this method to make it text string:

```
(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', my_string).encode('ascii', 'ignore')).decode()
```

Comment: Thank you, the solution works fine. Just an observation. It wasn't necessary to add 'uff-8' as an argument to `decode`. Why?

Comment: @Alexis Default encoding is 'utf-8'. So you can omit this value in decode() Please mark answer as accepted, if problem is fixed. Thank you

Comment: Now I understand why. Thank you for your time @gajendragarg